# Is Javascript LBYL or EAFP?

Tags: javascript, code-structure

There are two programming approaches: **EAFP** (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) and **LBYL** (Look Before You Leap). First approach presumes doing something that can cause an exception, then handling this exception and second approach presumes using `if` statements. So is Javascript **EAFP** or **LBYL**?

Comment: The question as posed makes no sense: JavaScript, being a programming *language*, is not a programming *approach*. How you approach programming in JavaScript is entirely up to you. You can choose to check everything first, or you can choose to "do something and catch any exceptions thrown".

Comment: @meriton I asked this question, because many programming languages has certain approach. For example, Python is defenitely EAFP, while C/C++ are LBYL

Comment: I completely agree with the question. After finding out that javascript does not have a good error system, the answer is clearly LBYL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top answer to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/440wib/lbyl_or_eafp/) sums up my opinion on this pretty well, but I'll give my 2 bits.

Definitely Look Before You Leap.

Consider this code.

```js
const thing = {};

try {
  thing.forestryServices.apply();
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

thing.forestryServices = {
  apply: "surprise goombas"
}

try {
  thing.forestryServices.apply();
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

The error returned in both cases is an object of type Error. Trying to recover from those errors would be significantly more difficult than doing the required checks ahead of time to make sure your object is valid for what you're trying to do to it.

Comment: Nothing prevents a JavaScript function from returning specific errors that callers can use to handle error in a specific way. Also, sometimes errors can be handled generically without needing to know how exactly things went wrong. There is a reason both the Promise and rxjs support error parameters ...

Comment: Sure, but the errors in my code example are both core JavaScript errors. One is "property apply does not exist on undefined" and the other is "apply is not a function." But the data type for both is Error.